# Is there anything that will add extension using statement suggestions in C#?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, using-statement

Is there an add-in or extension for Visual Studio that will do what Ctrl-. does for types/classes.  Which is to say that while the cursor is on a type which VS doesn't recognize, and typing Ctrl-. it will provide some suggestions.  Typically the suggestions are either add using statements, or fully qualify the type.  But, for `extensions methods` there is no similar short cut for adding `using statements`.  Maybe there is a plug-in, add-in, or extension, or something that provides this feature?

Comment: CodeRush also supposedly does this but I have never gotten it to work: http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2011/03/23/importing-namespace-references-for-extension-methods-in-coderush-for-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Yeah -- it looks like it *is* a dupe of the the "auto-resolve" question.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper includes this functionality as part of its [Import Symbol Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Import_Symbol_Completion) feature.